# Getting error while trying to add columns dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My requirement is to add try_convert(int, left(employee_id, charindex('-', employee_id) - 1)) to columns dynamically but I am getting error.

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

```
declare @cols varchar(max)
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @cols=a,b,c,d
set @sql= 'select' + @cols + ',[employee],' +' cast(left(employee_id, charindex('-', employee_id) - 1) as int) as [employee_id]  from Employee'

Select @sql
```

Comment: `@cols` is a **scalar** value. `set @cols=a,b,c,d` makes no sense; it can't have the value of 4 undefined columns.

Comment: probably you mean set @cols='a,b,c,d';

Comment: Stop cramming your code together - especially when you are attempting dynamic sql. You have additional errors yet to be found.

Comment: `selecta,b,c,d,[employee],` would be a bad start.

Comment: Aside: Use `nvarchar(max)` and `quotename` on each column name. I hope these columns are not coming from user input...

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes here:

```
charindex('-', employee_id) - 1)
```

So that full line needs to become:

```
set @sql= 'select ' + @cols + ',[employee],' +' cast(left(employee_id, charindex(''-'', employee_id) - 1) as int) as [employee_id]  from Employee'
```

With what you have now, the 's are breaking the string so the - is outside of your dynamic SQL, causing SQL Server to see it as the first part of your string minus the second, thus the error.